# What is gold good for?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a good supply of gold; however I do not know what to do with it all! Golden armour and tools wear out too fast to be useful, so what do I do with all my gold?

Comment: But golden armor and tools LOOK cool, especially with some of the texture packs.

Comment: Petition to rename this question to "GOLD! What is it good for? Absolutely nothin'?"

Comment: Amusingly, Minecraft imitates life. Gold is softer than iron and useless to build with. Though rare there's ample for its few uses (jewellery and dentistry). Nevertheless *in real life* gold is hugely valuable, [to the bewilderment of some economists](http://web.mit.edu/krugman/www/goldbug.html). I like that gold is (almost) useless in Minecraft, because it subverts the computer game rule 'rare items are better'.

Comment: @ColonelPanic Almost useless? How do you figure? Have you never tried enchanting it? Gold tools/equipment have the greatest enchantment potential (by far,) in vanilla. And as of 1.9 there is now a Mending enchantment, which allows you to siphon XP as repair points for the item. This balances gold even further.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'm not really a Minecraft player, but a quick glance at [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold) indicates that you should (like with other metals) first smelt raw gold ore in to **Gold Ingots**, using a furnace.

These ingots can then be used to craft weapons and armour (which you don't want), but also used to create **[Clocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock)** and **[Powered Rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail)**.

You can also combine 9 ingots in to a **Gold Block**, these can then be used for construction (if you want a nice golden house or something) or these ingots can then be used to craft a **[Golden Apple](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Golden_Apple)**, which instantly restores your health.

Given the supposed rare nature of Gold within the game and the items you can create with it, I would presume Gold's most important usage is in the creation of Powered Rail, which (from what I see here) *vastly* increases your construction options with mine carts.

Comment: Gold tools wear out fastest but also mine fastest, still doesn't make them that useful however!

Comment: Don't Diamond tools mine fastest?  I thought Gold tools were just reskins of Wood tools

Comment: @Retrosaur check the [wiki page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Gold_Pickaxe#Speed_and_durability) for Pickaxes and you'll see that gold is faster for most things, although it seems it's slower for many 'high level' blocks (and without dropping even). Also, gold is universally fastest for [shovels](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Shovel#Speed_and_durability) and [axes](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Axe#Speed_and_durability) though, and in *every* case it has the lowest durability making this almost always a waste of gold.

Comment: Gold items have a better chance of getting certain enchantments. http://0xcafebabe.com/2012/05/minecraft-1-3-probabilities/  If your *really* need that enchantment it may be worth the reduced durability.

Answer (score 14):

You can use it to create:

- gold blocks for decoration or for a beacon base
- [powered rails](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Powered_Rail) for a massive minecart empire.
- a [clock](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock)
- [gold nuggets](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_Nugget) that make golden apples, carrots, melons and fireworks.

Answer (score 8):

With the new [villager trading](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) feature that was added in version 1.3 you can now buy and sell items using [emeralds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Emerald) as currency. All of the 5 villager types [have a chance](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#cite_note-gold-2) that they may offer to buy gold from you, but a [Blacksmith](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Blacksmith) is more likely to offer this trading option.

So, if you don't use your gold for much else, I'd say hold on to it until you find a villager who will buy it from you. It's a good way to amass emeralds.

Comment: Although the gold for emeralds tends to be expensive, you need to trade once to get them to unlock their next thing ... and for blacksmiths, they might sell diamond tools or armor

Answer (score 5):

[This article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_%28Ingot%29) contains a list of all of the uses of gold, however in general gold is only used for Clocks, powered rails, and as a fancy looking block. It can be used to craft armor and tools as well, but they have such low durability you should never use it for that purpose. It also needs to be mentioned that gold is a somewhat rare resource, so you don't want to waste it.

Overall, the most useful application is powered rails. This is because powered rails are *essential* for making minecart tracks, and you'll often need quite a few of them. Clocks on the other hand are only used to tell the time, which can be helpful, but is far from required. However you only need to make one clock, so most people will spend the gold to make one. Finally they can be used as blocks as well, although it's more practical to use something else. However if you have a lot of extra gold lying around, it can be a nice way of making your base look nice and fancy.

Answer (score 4):

Another interesting feature of gold is that it has much higher [enchantability](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchantment_Mechanics#How_Enchantments_Are_Chosen) than any other material in the game; meaning that when you use gold items, you are more likely to get a more powerful enchantment.  For many things, this just isn't interesting, Gold armor with the protection enchantment is not better than plain iron armor; but there's no real downside to having a diving helmet that happens to be made of gold; so for many of those sorts of speciality bonuses, Gold items are still quite good.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what everyone else said, there was an update a few months back that made gold tools work twice as fast as they normally did.  However, their durability is still the same.

Comment: I wondered when that happened

Comment: I can't remember exactly when off hand :(