# Minecraft Gold Trouble

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found some gold ore while mining and used it to make a gold, sword, and an axe. Over a span of 3 minecraft days, they all broke! Can someone explain why the gold tools broke so fast?

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27413/what-is-gold-good-for?rq=1

Comment: [Gold is a very soft metal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold#Characteristics).

Answer (score 18):

Gold has only 33 uses, or durability. It will protect you very well and is almost as fast as diamond, but it is a soft metal, and therefore it breaks very fast. [This link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_Sword) shows that a gold sword only has 33 uses. [This link](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gold_Helmet#Defense_points) shows that gold armor protects you as much as chain armor, but is only better than leather armor in terms of durability. Therefore, you'd be better off using iron for tools. Save your gold for other things, such as golden apples, golden carrots, glistering melons, and fireworks. As @Ender suggested above, you can find the complete list in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27413/what-is-gold-good-for?rq=1).

Comment: With some tools, it is even faster than diamond, but a gold pickaxe can only mine the same blocks as a wood pickaxe.

Comment: The one advantage of gold is it is more easily enchanted (ie. greater enchantment for the same number of experience levels). However overall it is minimum practicality maximum bling.